# asp.net mvc core 1.0.1 with ef core 1.0.1 cannot retrieve saved one to many relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just started looking into asp mvc core. According to MS poco databases remain the same.

Now all the code below has been working flawlessly on asp mvc 4 and also everything is saved in the database; As verified by sqlserverexplorer on visual studio 2015 update 3.

I can retrieve the data but after a while or after i restart the application and try to retrieve the property it says null, although I can view the data in the database.

Things tried

1. reinstalled vs
2. reinstalled mvc core
3. [Viewed the examples on the official documentation/tutorial site](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model.html)
   They use ICollection instead of List but they also says that you can use either.
4. builder.Entity().HasMany(u => u.storymode).WithOne(c => c.user);****
   in the databse context OnModelCreating method.

***This line was making it keep the relationships until the application was restarted, hence it only saved the relations which were saved after the application started and lost after it restarted.

The current behavior is that it saves the data but it is not being retrieved.

Extra points
I am saving the data via a function defined below, that function belongs to a class which is injected as per the asp.net mvc core guidelines in the ConfigureServices method in the startup class.

My poco class is

```
public class modelsall
{
    public virtual int modelsallId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public virtual string email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public virtual string title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public virtual string extra { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public virtual DateTime startdate { get; set; }

    public virtual string imageblob { get; set; }

    public virtual List<comments> comments { get; set; }

    public virtual List<storyfacequotes> faceq { get; set; }

    //Tried adding this in desperation
    //[ForeignKey("storypages")]
    //public virtual int storyId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<story> pages { get; set; }

    //Tried adding this after a blogpost said it might help
    public virtual ApplicationUser user { get; set; }

    public virtual whatisit typ { get; set; }


}
```

Method for creating and saving

```
public async Task<bool> AddMainStory(string email, modelsall modelsall)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await GetUser(email);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        modelsall.email = user.Email;
        modelsall.user = user;
        _context.models.Add(modelsall);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (user.mode == null)
        {
            user.mode = new List<modelsall>();
        }
        user.mode.Add(modelsall);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
```

property defined in ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<modelsall> mode { get; set; }
}
```

PS: I could not find a tag for asp.net mvc core, although, mvc5 is considered mvc core according to MS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and not looking into the docs properly the first time,

you need this for making relationships

```
builder.Entity().HasMany(u => u.storymode).WithOne(c => c.user);
```

**** in the databse context OnModelCreating method.

but the entire thing resets if the application restarts so not an ideal solution.

For now you can either search each time, not much effect for small applications or use asp 5 and ef6.

[Here is a list of features not included in ef core as of now.](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/features.html)